# In what sense is the complex $\mathscr{L}^\bullet$ unique?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

[image]

This is in Section III.12. *Algebraic Geometry* by Hartshorne. Assume $X\to\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is a projective morphism of Noetherian schemes. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be coherent over $X$, flat over $A$.

Proposition 12.2 says that there exists a bounded complex of finite free $A$-modules $\mathscr{L}^\bullet$ such that
$$H^i(X,\mathscr{F}\otimes_AM)\cong H^i(\mathscr{L}^\bullet\otimes_AM)$$
for every $A$-module $M$.

Here are my questions:

- In what sense is $\mathscr{L}^\bullet$ unique? Is $\mathscr{L}^\bullet$ unique up to chain homotopy or up to quasi-isomorphisms? Now I only know these two notions of uniqueness.
- Which category should $\mathscr{L}^\bullet$ situate? Does the association $\mathscr{F}\mapsto\mathscr{L}^\bullet$ define a functor? I expect some derived category, and the functor needs answer to the question above.
- What are generalizations of this proposition? This is vague. Actually I want to know the modern formulation of the proposition.

Comment: $\mathscr{L}^{\bullet}=Rf_*\mathscr{F}$, an object of the (bounded) derived category $D(Y)$. The nontrivial point is that it is a *perfect* object in $D(Y)$, commuting with base change. You can have a look at chapter 36 in the Stacks project.

Comment: In particular, see \[Tag [0B91](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B91) (2)\] for existence of the 'Grothendieck complex' $\mathscr L^{\bullet}$ (using \[Tags [08EB](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08EB) and [0657](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0657)\] for translation to the case where the base $Y$ is affine).

Comment: The discussion of this in Chapter 2 of Mumford's "Abelian varieties" is particularly short and clear.  I usually tell students to skip that section of Hartshorne's book and read it instead in Mumford's book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your questions:

> In what sense is $\mathscr{L}^\bullet$ unique? Is $\mathscr{L}^\bullet$ unique up to chain homotopy or up to
> quasi-isomorphisms? Now I only know these two notions of uniqueness.

It is unique up to quasi-isomorphism. Of course, if $Y$ is affine this uniqueness can be upgraded to uniqueness up to homotopy because in this case the complex $\mathscr{L}^\bullet$ corresponds to a complex of finitely generated projective modules over the global sections of the structure sheaf of $Y$.

> Which category should $\mathscr{L}^\bullet$ situate? Does the
> association $\mathscr{F} \mapsto \mathscr{L}^\bullet$ define a
> functor? I expect some derived category, and the functor needs answer
> to the question above.

As it is remarked by @abx for $f \colon X \to Y$ projective and $\mathscr{F}$ *flat* over $Y$, the functor takes coherent flat complexes to perfect complexes, where we consider the category of perfect complexes $\mathrm{Perf}(Y)$ as a subcategory of the derived category.

> What are generalizations of this proposition? This is vague. Actually
> I want to know the modern formulation of the proposition.

Recently the theorem has been generalized as follows, for $f \colon X \to Y$ proper and pseudo-coherent the functor $\mathbf{R}f_*$ restricts to a functor
$$
\mathbf{R}f_* \colon \mathrm{Perf}(f) \longrightarrow \mathrm{Perf}(Y)
$$
where $\mathrm{Perf}(f)$ denotes the relative perfect complexes on $X$ over $Y$, that, whenever $Y$ is regular, are all bounded pseudo-coherent complexes. Notice that the Noetherian hypothesis is not needed.

For more details, see [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00209-023-03294-7), especially section 3. As a bonus, in section 5 the semicontinuity is discussed.